# 400 Error on TimThumb

Tags: wordpress, bad-request, http-status-code-400

I'm testing a WordPress plugin that uses TimThumb.

On one server (GoDaddy) I'm getting a 400 (Bad Request) error whenever I request the timthumb.php file from the plugins directory. However, an identical request on a different server works just fine.

/wp-content/plugins/wp-vimeo/timthumb.php

I'm puzzled. I can request other files in the same directory just fine. Could it be a permissions issue? I would have expected a 403 if that were the case.

Comment: What parameters are you passing to the script? Like the src for example.

Comment: Yep, I'm having the same issue. I have seen others say change the permissions for the directory to 755, but I have done that and I'm not having any luck. I read that it uses PHP-GD is that installed on a basic godaddy hosting account?

Comment: Same here. WP has been updated to 3.2.1, Woo object to 1.7.1 and Woo framework to 4.5.3. it worked as expected on another site that uses Object (hosted on Bluehost). Not here though (godaddy hosting)
I downloaded a fresh Object theme and uploaded to the server but still no luck.
Opening a broken image to another tab gives me that URL:
http://www.laboutique-galerie.com/wp-content/themes/object/functions/thumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/2011/09/CSTM01-680x1024.jpg&w=220&h=220&zc=1&q=100 I updated the permission on GoDaddy to Read/write but that's not changing anything. Is there another way to ch

Answer (score 1):

For Windows hosting add IUSR (or whatever account your app pool is running) to wp-content with read/write.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving my site from a `Window Server` to a `Linux Server`. Still on godaddy. [a]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because my images were to be resized.
If you copy paste the timthumb url int the browser and receive the error that the image size is to big.   I had to either change the file size of the images or change the timthumb's setting to handle bigger images.

This line in the timthumb.php file:

```
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 3000000);          // file size limit to prevent    possible DOS attacks (roughly 3 megabytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers don't seem to address the issue directly. You can paste the URL in of the timthumb call. In your browser you should get diagnostic error form timthumb. Usually it is because there is not a writable cache directory for timthumb to use to make the Image it serves.

Answer (score 0):

Inside timthumb.php you'll find this line:

`header ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 400 Bad Request');`

This is triggered whenever there's an error: inaccessible cache, required query string variables missing, etc. I have found that link checkers like Google Webmaster Tools and Integrity sometimes remove the query string and check the validity of the root files. Of course without the query string timthumb.php will then return the 400 error.

To tidy this up I comment out the above line.